# Adding new package breaks the .NET 5 application

Tags: c#, .net-5, kestrel-http-server, identitymodel

I've been trying to figure out why my console application fails the instant I introduce a new package. Using `IdentityModel.OidcClient` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel` **only** works, but when adding `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` it throws exception. I don't reference the new package in code either, I just add it to the project.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Clone https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples.git
2. Upgrade *NetCoreConsoleClient* to .NET 5 (update packages).
3. Remove *Serilog.Sinks.Literate* obsolete package.
4. Remove call to `.WriteTo.LiterateConsole` for SeriLog in Program.cs and add `using IdentityModel.Client`.
5. Add `CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken()` parameter for `InvokeAsync` method in `SystemBrowser` class. The signature for the `IBrowser` interface has changed, the new method should look like this: `public async Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())`
6. Run application and login with alice/alice. Acquiring token is successful.
7. Add package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`.
8. Run application. It now throws exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` when writing to the http response.

The exception occurs in `LoopbackHttpListener.SetResult` when writing to the response: `ctx.Response.WriteAsync("<h1>You can now return to the application.</h1>");`

Why does adding a package **only**, have such an impact to the runtime?

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>NetCoreConsoleClient</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel.OidcClient" Version="3.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Complete exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.CreateResponseHeader(Boolean appCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProduceStart(Boolean appCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.InitializeResponseAsync(Int32 firstWriteByteCount)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseStream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponseWritingExtensions.WriteAsync(HttpResponse response, String text, Encoding encoding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponseWritingExtensions.WriteAsync(HttpResponse response, String text, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ConsoleClientWithBrowser.LoopbackHttpListener.SetResult(String value, HttpContext ctx) in C:\Users\stefa\Source\Repos\IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples\NetCoreConsoleClient\src\NetCoreConsoleClient\SystemBrowser.cs:line 172
```

## Solution

Get rid of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`, change the SDK to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` and everything works. Thanks to @JHBonarius for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Please give more details on step 5. You seem to be declaring a local variable, but you say you're adding a parameter... And what exactly throws?

Comment: Note that just upgrading major versions of packages AND updrading core 2.0 to 5.0 AND removing packages, without making modifications to the code, could as well be the cause. That's a major risk for unstable behavior.

Comment: More modifications are required. Need to add `using IdentityModel.Client;` to Program.cs and need to remove `.WriteTo.LiterateConsole(outputTemplate:...` from Program.cs.

Comment: @JHBonarius, I've added some more context, and I have also tried this without upgrading the repository, but by starting a new project and just copied relevant code over. Using correct packages.

Comment: Please add the exception that is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown in

```
private void SetResult(string value, HttpContext ctx)
{
    try
    {
        ctx.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        // below
        ctx.Response.WriteAsync("<h1>You can now return to the application.</h1>"); <--- here
        // ^^
        ctx.Response.Body.Flush();

        _source.TrySetResult(value);
    }
...
```

I have two comments already.

1. `WriteAsync` is an async/Task. You need to await it.
2. your 'catch' block there will also throw in this case...... you have no 'catch' for that...

Anyhow, I think the problem is you adding a .NET 5.0 version of the new package (and remember that packages often pull in other packages which they rely on) to a quite old project. Especially with ASP.net it's not that simple. Interfaces have changed. Instantiation methods have changed. You often need to put in more work.

Change the version of `Microsoft.Extentions.Configuration.Json` back to v3.1.13 and the problem seems to be gone...

Comment: The code is cloned from the IdentityModel repository, I've added async/await to my original code. I'm wondering why just adding the package could have such an impact to the other assemblies. I was under the impression that .NET 5 adressed the DLL-hell previously experienced in the .Net Framework. I'll take a deeper look at the actual files in the bin folder.

Comment: @Vincent no, that's already with .NET Core. And "DLL-hell" is something else then what you are doing. You are upgrading from .NET core 2.0 to .NET 5.0: that's not a trivial task. Many things change with such a major version upgrade. Things * might * work, but they could break anytime.
(In my company we're also trying to upgrade projects to .NET 5.0, but it's weeks and weeks of work.)

Comment: i was sure NetStandard was sufficient for net 5 compatibility. I’ll try rewriting.

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same issue.

```
 ctx.Response.StatusCode = 200;
 ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
 ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Date", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString());
 await ctx.Response.WriteAsync(content);
 await ctx.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
```

Setting the Date Header solved it 4 me, since that is, whats failing in Kestrel.Core

Comment: Yep, adding the "Date" value on the Header solved it. Thanks. I have to take out the `new` from DateTimeOffset though.`ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Date", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString());`

Comment: Surprisingly it just works! Suggest to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with my ASP.NET Core 2.2 project. Making sure I didn't have any Microsoft.Extensions.X packages greater than 3.1.X fixed the issue for me.

Comment: That may be, but it doesn't really answer the question since this is _specifically_ about .NET 5.0. Obviously, removing contemporary library versions isn't going to solve this for them.